# Setting PublicationMonitor.ConnectionContext throws a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, replication, nullreferenceexception

At first I tried this:

```
var conn = new ServerConnection(@"SMTDEV\SQL2008", "login", "password");
var pubMon = new PublicationMonitor("PRMDemoRep", "distribution", @"SMTDEV\SQL2008", "PRMDemo", conn);
```

If I set a break point on the second line, I am able to run the following code successfully from the immediate window:

```
conn.ExecuteScalar("select 1");
```

So I know the ServerConnection is working properly and definitely not null.  The other parameters are all strings so there should be no issue there, but I keep getting a NullReferenceException when I run the second line.

I also tried using the parameterless constructor of PublicationMonitor and I am able to set each of the string properties this way but when I go to set the ConnectionContext to my ServerConnection then I get the NullReferenceException.

Anyone have any ideas why in the world that would happen?

EDIT:  I have also just tried this with the ReplicationMonitor class and am running into the same problem.  I have tried to point it to multiple servers, but am always met with a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Is "SMTDEV\SQL2008" the name of your distributor?  Are you using a remote distributor by any chance?

Comment: Also, can you View Detail... in the Exception Assistant and see it provides any additional details?  Specifically, check if there is additional details in the InnerException.

Comment: Brandon, the publisher and distributor are both SMTDEV\SQL2008.  However, SMTDEV is not the development machine on which I'm running the code so... the distributor is not remote in relation to the publisher but obviously it is remote to the development machine.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams And no, there are no other details and no inner exception.  I've been programming in .net almost since it began and this is the first time I've ever gotten this exception where the problem wasn't immediately obvious and totally my fault.  This time the exception is not my own fault (the code is only a few lines...  I'm quite certain I'm not missing anything here).  So I'm thinking this could be a bug on Microsoft's part.

Comment: It's hard to say for sure.  I am able to run the same exact code in my test environment and it works.  What type of replication are you using?

Comment: @BrandonWilliams Merge Replication.  Are you running the code from a remote machine as well?  I think I'll setup Visual Studio on the Publisher/Distributor machine and see if it still gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by checking what version of the dll I was using. My project was referencing the 2008 assemblies (100/SDK folder) however my local shared SQL components had been upgraded to 2012. When I changed the reference to 2012 assemblies (110/SDK) it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know if this would have fixed my problem and this isn't something I'm going to go back and check at this point in time, but even if it's not the right answer this is probably the closest thing to a good answer this question's gonna get so I'm marking it :)